# How to upload images to aws s3 and store the url in mongoDB using node express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, mongoose

How to upload multiple images to aws s3 and store the public url in mongoDB using node express and mongoose

Schema

```
const shopSchema = new Schema({
  shopName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  ownerName:{
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
  phoneNumber:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  passbook: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  certificate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [],
    
   },
  password:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  isVerified:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false,
    required:true
  }
  ,
  foodId: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Food',
  }]
});
```

i have already used multer and stored in local device but i have problem in deployment

Need to store the urls in images,certificate,passbook fields

Comment: You can find plenty of tutorials for image file upload to S3.

Comment: can you please send any link. I have explored but my form contains 3 files filed and i need to upload it to aws s3 and retrive url

Comment: 1. https://medium.com/@iamsohail/how-to-upload-multiple-files-parallelly-to-amazon-s3-3b9ac3630806               
2. https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/uploading-a-file-multiple-to-amazon-web-services-aws-s3-bucket-with-node-js-in-express-8e268ab12422

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Do you have a relevant link for your question?

Answer (score 1):

Still this question is unclear to me guess no one interested in saving links to MongoDb

here what I used as workaround hope this problem

```
const God = require("../models/God");
const { verifyToken } = require("../middleware/verify");
const router = require("./users");

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const uuid = require("uuid/v4");
const path = require("path");

// Upload Audio & image to S3 bucket

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
});

const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "");
  },
});

const uploadMulter = multer({ storage }).array("files");

const uploadAudio = async (filename, file) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      Key: filename,
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Body: file,
      ACL: "public-read",
    };

    await s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR", err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("RUNNING COCOOLLl");
        resolve(data.Location);
      }
    });
  });
};

// Creating Gods
router.post("/create/god", uploadMulter, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("UPLOAD MEDIA FOR GOD");
  console.log(req.files);

  const { name } = req.body;
  const newGod = new God({ name });

  // res.send("DONE")

  console.log("AUDIO/Image UPLOAD");
  let folder;

  try {
    req.files.forEach(async (file) => {
      if (file.mimetype.includes("audio")) folder = "bhajans";
      else folder = "images";

      let filename = `god/${folder}/${uuid() + file.originalname}`;
      let mediaLink = `https://${process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${filename}`;
      newGod.bhajans.push(mediaLink);

      try {
        const link = await uploadAudio(filename, file.buffer);
        // console.log(link);
        // newGod.bhajans.push(link);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in uploadig media", error);
      }
    });

    try {
      const saveGod = await newGod.save();
      console.log("SAVED GOD ::::::::::::", saveGod);
      res.status(200).json("God added");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error in saving data to DB!!!!!!");
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("ERROR :) :)");
  }
});
```